# How to create something happen when time = x

Tags: processing

I have a question about timers in Processing. I want to make a square spawn after every second that passes. Would I use a for loop, an if statement, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the `millis()` function or the `frameCount` variable in an `if` statement.

Something like this:

```
void draw(){
   if(frameCount % 60 == 0){
      //do something
   }
}
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).